# Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

I am studying Professor Rick Durrett's book "Probability: Theory and Examples" and would greatly appreciate feedback on the validity of my proof.

Claim: If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, then $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$.

Definitions: $X_n\to X$ in probability means for every $\epsilon>0$, $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Given a sequence of distribution functions $F_n$, $F_n\to F$ weakly (also known as convergence in distribution) means $F_n(y)\to F(y)$ for all points $y$ that are continuity points of $F$.

Given a sequence of random variables $X_n$ with $F_n$ the distribution function of each $X_n$, $X_n\to X$ weakly means $F_n\to F$ weakly.

Proof: Let $g$ be a continuous, bounded function. Recall that $X_n\to X$ in probability implies that for every subsequence $X_{n(m)}$, there exists a convergent sub-subsequence $X_{n(m_k)}$ so that $X_{n(m_k)}\to X$ almost surely, and hence $g(X_{n(m_k)})\to g(X)$ almost surely. Then $Eg(X_{n(m_k)})\to Eg(X)$ by the dominated convergence theorem. Since the subsequence $X_{n(m)}$ was arbitrary, we have $Eg(X_n)\to Eg(X)$. Further, since $g$ was arbitrary, $X_n\to X$ weakly.

Thanks a bunch in advance for the feedback!

Facts I used:

- $X_n\to X$ in probability iff for every subsequence of random variables $X_{n(m)}$, there exists a further subsequence $X_{n(m_k)}$ such that $X_{n(m_k)}\to X$ almost surely.
- If $y_n$ is a sequence of elements in a topological space such that for every subsequence $y_{n(m)}$, there exists a further subsequence $y_{n(m_k)}\to y$, then $y_n\to y$.
- $X_n\to X$ weakly iff for every bounded continuous function $g$ we have $Eg(X_n)\to Eg(X)$.

Comment: Looks good.  One thing to be gleaned from your proof is the convergence-in-probability form of the Dominated Convergence Theorem: If $X_n\to X$ in probability and $|X_n|\le Y$ with $\Bbb E[Y]<\infty$, then $\lim_n\Bbb E[X_n]=\Bbb E[X]$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input John! Good point. I find myself reproducing the "a.s. convergence means $lim EX_n=EX$ via sub-subsequence convergence for every subsequence" argument a lot. I should just write your statement and be done with it