# $X_n \to X$ in weakly, or in distribution iff $X_n-X\to 0$ weakly.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

$X_n \to X$ in weakly, or in distribution iff $X_n-X\to 0$ weakly.

This seems to be true by Levy's Continuity Theorem. However, from the definition of weak convergence, i.e., $$\int f dP_{X_n} \to \int f dP_X \; \text{for all} \; f\in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$$ I don't see how the equivalence holds. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could clear me up on this.

I need this result to show that $E(R\wedge |X_n-X|)\to 0$ below from the fact that $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $f(x)=R\wedge |x|$ is a bounded continuous function.
[image]

Comment: That's because they are not equivalent. ($X_n - X \to 0$ is the stronger statement.) Convergence in distribution tells almost no information about function aspect of $X_n$ and $X$. So you have no way of comparing values of $X_n$ and $X$. As an extreme example, let $X_n = X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. standard normal. Then $X_n \to Y$ in distribution and $X_n -Y \to \sqrt{2}Y$ in distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee Then how can I make sense of the below part? I need $E[f(X_n - X)] \to 0$ to get the final result, but only have $E(f(X_n))\to E(f(X))$ from the hypothesis $X_n \to X$ in distribution.

Comment: You cannot do that in general. Taking advantage of this fact to the opposite direction, however, if $X_n \to X$ in distribution then you can realize a sequence $\tilde{X}_n$ and $\tilde{X}$ on some probability space such that $\tilde{X}_n \stackrel{d}{=} X_n$ and $\tilde{X} \stackrel{d}{=} X$ and $\tilde{X}_n \to \tilde{X}$ almost surely. I suspect this trick is what the proof is adopting.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $X_n-X\to 0$ in distribution implies that $X_n\to X$ in distribution. Indeed, if $X_n-X\to 0$ in distribution then $X_n-X\to 0$ in probability hence $X_n\to X$ in probability [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608792/convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-in-distribution-of-random-variabl?rq=1) $X_n\to X$ in distribution.

But the converse does not necessarily hold. Indeed, the only information that $X_n\to X$ in distribution is not enough to deduce something on the distribution of $X_n-X$. Indeed, if $X$ is a symmetric random variable (that is, $X$ and $-X$ have the same law), define $X_{2n}=X$ and $X_{2n-1}=-X$. Then $X_n\to X$ in distribution but $X_{2n}-X=0$ while $X_{2n+1}-X=-2X$.